# Inbox notification won't go away

Tags: bug, status-norepro, notifications, global-inbox

Since this evening's breakdown ("*site is in read-only mode*"), after I logged back in, I've got a dangling <kbd>you have new inbox messages" notification</kbd>. I did

1. open the inbox - no message was highlighted as "new"
2. closed the inbox (even after having visited the links) by mousing out - the big red <kbd>1</kbd> disappeared
3. reloaded the page (and even restarted the browser) - the notification was there again

What is happening here? Can I fix this myself?

During the outage, I had tried to open my inbox, but fetching the messages failed. Could this have something to do with this?

Comment: There was no breakdown; the site was migrated from Oregon to a new datacenter on the East Coast. RO mode was entirely planned and on purpose. Give it a little longer, not everything is *out* of RO mode just yet.

Comment: For me, logging out and restarting the browser resolved the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just wait it out; it should all be over soon.

If you're getting notifications on your phone, set it on something soft so it doesn't make too much of a racket.

Comment: Waiting did work :-) Didn't have issues with a phone